# FactoryGirl ( Admin would have been guessed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am reading through FactoryGirl documentation, but I didn't understand the idea of a class being guessed, what do the below comments mean?

Thanks in advance

```
# This will guess the User class
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name "Joe"
    last_name "Lincol"
    admin false
  end

# This will use the User class (Admin would have been guessed)
  factory :admin, class: User do
    first_name "Admin"
    last_name "User"
    admin true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When deciding which class to instantiate, FactoryGirl tries to guess by using the name of the factory. In the first example, `factory :user`, it will instantiate a `User` class. In the second example, `factory :admin`, if you don't specify the `class: User` parameter, FactoryGirl would try to look for an `Admin` class, which is probably not what you want.

The `admin` (with `true` or `false` value) from the factory definitions is just a field in the `User` class, it has no effect on how FactoryGirl is looking for classes to instantiate.

Comment: Oh I see now. Thanks it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

Admin is not been guessed.

The boolean flag `admin true` tells that the user is an admin.